# How to removed a subdomain on .Net Core with RewriteOptions.AddRedirect

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We are migrating a web site that has a subdomain for the site English version. It is english.example.com, but now we are consolidating all languages under [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

We test the below option but it is not working.

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
                    .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()
                    .AddRedirect(@"(www)(\.english)(\.\w*\.com\/[\w*\-*\%*\/]*)", @"{$1}{$3}", (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently);
            app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Should we use a custome rule?

Comment: Could you please tell me what's you requirement? Do you mean you want to remove all the subdomain and redirect to www.example.com?

Comment: i think problem with regular expression, what will happen if you try with this.
(www)(\.english)(\.\w*\.com)

Comment: Brando Zhang, we want to force the everything (example.com and english.example.com) into www.example.com. The issue is that there are many links on the internet that points to english.example.com, and we want to redirect all of them into www.example.com. Since we are doing the AddRedirectToWwwPermanent(), first on the RewriteOptions(). Current english.example.com, are redirected to www.english.example.com. We want to delete “English.” from the url.

Comment: If the url is test.example.com, you should also redirect to the www.example.com?

Comment: Brando Zhang, yes.